# Referencing a Text Field with Meteor/React

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to reference the data from a text field for usage. Here is my code, and I am using Meteor and React in order to do so. I am also using Bootstrap, maybe that's conflicting.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class HomeSubmission extends React.Component {

    redirectToSubmission(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        FlowRouter.go('/submit');
        let question = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.question).value.trim();
        console.log(question);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron">
            <div className="container">



                                      <h1 className="text-center">Ask</h1>
                                      <p className="text-center">Ask a question, get an answer.</p>
                                  </div>

                <form onSubmit={this.redirectToSubmission.bind(this)}>
                    <div class="form-group" className="text-center">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="question" placeholder="Ask your question..." />
                        <br/> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It says question is an unresolved variable, and when I say ref="question" it says this is an invalid tag, but that's how it is done. Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, in recent React versions, `this.refs` holds the actual DOM nodes.

Comment: So how do I make this call?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't change the route before you get the value (as it is likely to destroy the element).

`this.refs` now references the DOM nodes themselves, so there is no need to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` to obtain them.

You can use `this.refs.question.value.trim()` to get the trimmed value.

Comment: That doesn't work either for me. I tried both versions

Comment: Did you comment the Router redirection? What error are you getting? Try to reproduce this using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masteram/dpoz40yp/) or use it as reference. BTW, you are using `class` instead of `className`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not what you need, but you could use a controlled element. Something along these lines:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class HomeSubmission extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        question: '',
      };
    }

    redirectToSubmission(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let question = this.state.question;

        FlowRouter.go('/submit');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron">
              <div className="container">
                <h1 className="text-center">Ask</h1>
                <p className="text-center">Ask a question, get an answer.</p>
              </div>

              <form onSubmit={this.redirectToSubmission.bind(this)}>
                <div class="form-group" className="text-center">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    value={this.state.question}
                    onChange={(evt) => this.setState({question: evt.target.value.trim()})}
                    placeholder="Ask your question..."
                  />
                  <br/> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></div>
              </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```